# Hadoop webHDFS 400 IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I try to do sending a File in local to HDFS. Another command is fine, but there is a error when i create a file.

My command is below:

> curl -i -X PUT -T Documents/Node/test.json
>   "http://localhost:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/test.json?op=create&user.name=hadoop"

And return's result is below:

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>
> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: 161 Connection: close
>
> {"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   null"}

I don't know why error is occur.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Hadoop, but you might be able to get more information from the exception stack trace in the server logs. To do so you may need to increase logging verbosity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem.

First i must submit a HTTP PUT request without sending the file data.
Then Hadoop returns a redirected a message to a datanode where the file data is to be written.
After that, Copy a location path and submit another HTTP PUT request using copied location with file data to be written.